# Problem in integration between Java and Slack using Webhooks

Tags: java, webhooks, slack

I have cucumber framework and want to integrate Java with Slack using Webhooks.
I've done the following classes:

```
public class Message {
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

}

```
public class MessageInterceptorController {
private final MessageSender messageSender;

public MessageInterceptorController(MessageSender messageSender) {
    this.messageSender = messageSender;
}

@PostMapping(path = "/messages/{userName}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@PathVariable String userName, @RequestBody Message message) {
    try {
        messageSender.sendMessage(userName, message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MessageSender {
private static final String HOOKS_URL = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/%s";
private static final Map<String, String> USER_TO_CHANNEL_WEBHOOK =
        Map.of("#channel_name", "T6TXXXXXX/B02LXXXXXX/YXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
public void sendMessage(String userName, Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String userChannelId = USER_TO_CHANNEL_WEBHOOK.get(userName);
    String userWebhookUrl = String.format(HOOKS_URL, userChannelId);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String messageJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(messageJson, headers);
    restTemplate.exchange(userWebhookUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
}
```

}

But I don't get any notifications in slack.
Thank you!

Comment: What does that post call at the end of the method return?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Sorry, but didn't get the question, which line is this. I am doing my best, but maybe I am doing something wrong. I am referring to this article https://dzone.com/articles/step-by-step-integration-with-slack-via-webhooks

Comment: And I'm asking what `restTemplate.exchange(userWebhookUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);` actually returns. Does it return a success or a failure? If it fails, does the body tell you anything useful?